# Computing intersections for each geometry in a table

Tags: python, postgis, sql, intersection, psycopg2

I have a table with many Linestrings and for each of these Linestrings I need to figure out which other Linestrings, from the same table, intersect with it.

If I recall correctly this gives me a Complexity of n^2. I tried doing this via a for loop in python and calling a SQL intersect() for each trajectory but it's taking forever: even after threading.

Is there a way of doing this computation in one SQL statement or perhaps using a different, less costly gis function call?

Here is the Python code (using psycopg2) that is called for each trajectory to compute other trajectories that intersect with it:

```
db_cursor.execute('''
                  SELECT
                      id
                  FROM trajectory
                  WHERE st_intersects((SELECT
                                            line_geometry
                                            FROM trajectory
                                            WHERE id = (%s)), trajectory.line_geometry);
                   ''', [trajectory[0]])
```

The database is PostgreSQL using PostGIS. Here are all the details for the trajectory table that I'm using:

[image]

Comment: Used SQL server and query would be nice and create table query and create index code

Comment: SQL Server or Postgis or something else?

Comment: Hi, I've added more information to my original post. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a self-join of the same table twice with different alias.

To find the intersection of one linestring with all others:

```
SELECT b.id
FROM trajectory a, trajectory b
WHERE a.id = %s AND a.id <> b.id AND ST_Intersects(a.line_geometry, b.line_geometry)
```

And to find all combinations of intersections of linestrings in the table:

```
SELECT  a.id || ' intersects with ' || b.id AS label
FROM trajectory a, trajectory b
WHERE a.id < b.id AND ST_Intersects(a.line_geometry, b.line_geometry)
```

Comment: I ran your second query and it completed in 3 hours. Much faster than my own. Thanks. In your second query why a.id < b.id? I can see having a.id != b.id so that it doesn't compare to itself by why less than?

Comment: Great question. a.id < b.id will make sure there is one match between the pair, otherwise you will see double counts for (symbolically) A.intersects(B) and B.intersects(A). Try it on a smaller subset to see.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `a.id < b.id` better than `a.id != b.id` as you will reduce the total number of queries?

Comment: yes, it will be half the number of rows, since each intersection pair won't be double counted. With `a.id < b.id`, there will have label `1 intersects with 2`, but with `a.id != b.id`, there will be an additional label `2 intersects with 1`. Try it!

Comment: I think I'm still missing something. Suppose I have a trajectory ID, 25705, that I want to find all the intersections for. When I use your first code example and count I get 891 results. When I use the second piece of code to compute everything and store it in a table, Intersections, and then do a search for that ID and count I get 387 results. These count() for both of these queries for a specific ID should be the same no?

Comment: With the second query style, you should have 387 IDs match from A, and 504 IDs match from B, which add up to 891 total. I didn't put these in the query, but it would be something like `a.id AS a_id, b.id AS b_id`.

Comment: I'm still confused. If your first query returns a count of 891 results that means there are 891 other trajectories that intersect with trajectory id 25705. If I run your second query that computes the intersections for all the other trajectories then when I search those results for trajectory id 25705 I should get the same count, no? Just to make sure I'm clear, the second query is supposed to do the same thing as the first except it does't it for all the trajectories.

Comment: Yes you should get the same 891 intersections within the second query results, but you need to search in two columns.